# Field accessibility in Profiles and Pagelayouts

Tags: profile, page-layout

I am learning salesforce administration basics.I have tried out access permission to one of the fields in the following ways.

Profile    Pagelayout

Readonly   Readonly

editable   Readonly

Readonly   Editable

In all theses cases , the field came as readonly.Usually salesforce widens the access not restrict rt? Confused

Comment: A couple of things to watch out for. 1 administrators can edit read only fields unless you clone the standard admin profile and remove this permission. 2. Some fields are always read only E.g. System fields, auto number and formula fields

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to watch out for. 1 administrators can edit read only fields unless you clone the standard admin profile and remove this permission. 2. Some fields are always read only E.g. System fields, auto number and formula fields